# Scipy sparse matrix alternative for getrow()

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am working with large sparse binary matrices. I have condensed them using `Scipy` sparse matrix implementation. The calculation of `Jaccard distance` from `scipy.spatial.distance` does not support direct operation on sparse matrices, so either:

1. convert the entire sparse matrix to dense and then operate on each   row as vectors which is **memory hungry**

   or
2. Loop through the sparse, grab each row using `getrow()` and operate.

   or
3. Write our own implementation to work on sparse matrices.

To put things to perspective, here is the sample code:

```
import scipy.spatial.distance as d
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

# benchmark performance 
X = np.random.random((3000, 3000))
# binarize
X[X > 0.3] = 0
X[X>0] = 1
mat =  csr_matrix(X)

a = np.zeros(3000)
a[4] = a[100] = a[22] =1
a = csr_matrix(a)

def jaccard_fast(v1,v2):
    common = v1.dot(v2.T)
    dis = (v1 != v2).getnnz()
    if common[0,0]:
        return 1.0-float(common[0,0])/float(common[0,0]+dis)
    else:
        return 0.0
    
def benchmark_jaccard_fast():
    for i in range(mat.shape[0]):
        jaccard_fast(mat.getrow(i),a)
        
def benchmark_jaccard_internal_todense():
    for v1,v2 in zip(mat.todense(),a.todense()):
         d.jaccard(v1,v2)
        
def benchmark_jaccard_internal_getrow():
    for i in range(mat.shape[0]):
        d.jaccard(mat.getrow(i),a)
        

print "Jaccard Fast:"
%time benchmark_jaccard_fast()
print "Jaccard Scipy (expanding to dense):"
%time benchmark_jaccard_internal_todense()
print "Jaccard Scipy (using getrow):"
%time benchmark_jaccard_internal_getrow()
```

where `jaccard_fast` is my own implementation. It appears that my implementation is faster than the internal one, on scipy sparse matrices, however `getrow()` seems to slow my implementation down. As I benchmark `jaccard_fast` against `scipy.spatial.distance.jaccard`, results are:

```
Jaccard Fast:
CPU times: user 1.28 s, sys: 0 ns, total: 1.28 s
Wall time: 1.28 s
Jaccard Scipy (expanding to dense):
CPU times: user 28 ms, sys: 8 ms, total: 36 ms
Wall time: 37.2 ms
Jaccard Scipy (using getrow):
CPU times: user 1.82 s, sys: 0 ns, total: 1.82 s
Wall time: 1.81 s
```

Any help on how to avoid the `getrow` bottleneck would be appreciated. I cannot afford to expand my sparse matrix using `todense()` due to memory limitations.

Comment: I think your `benchmark_jaccard_internal_todense` is cheating.  It's not doing the full 3000 iterations.  `a.todense()` is (1,3000), so zip on it and `mat` iterates on the least number of rows - ie. 1.

Comment: `benchmark_jaccard_internal_getrow` isn't a valid test since by your own admission `d.jaccard` does not work with sparse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sparse indexing is known for being slower, e.g. [How to read/traverse/slice Scipy sparse matrices (LIL, CSR, COO, DOK) faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37013115/how-to-read-traverse-slice-scipy-sparse-matrices-lil-csr-coo-dok-faster/37015740#37015740)

```
In [33]: timeit for row in mat: x=row  # sparse iteration
1 loops, best of 3: 510 ms per loop

In [35]: timeit for row in mat.todense(): x=row  # dense iteration
10 loops, best of 3: 175 ms per loop
```

but I find that your `d.jacard` is also slower when using sparse matrices

```
In [36]: ad=a.todense()

In [37]: timeit for row in mat.todense(): d.jaccard(row,ad) # all dense
1 loops, best of 3: 734 ms per loop

In [38]: timeit for row in mat: d.jaccard(row.todense(),ad) # inner dense
1 loops, best of 3: 1.69 s per loop

In [39]: timeit for row in mat: d.jaccard(row,a) # all sparse
1 loops, best of 3: 4.61 s per loop
```

Eliminating the `getrow` factor

```
In [40]: mrow=mat.getrow(0)

In [41]: mrowd=mrow.todense()

In [42]: timeit d.jaccard(mrow, a)  # one sparse row
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.32 ms per loop

In [43]: timeit d.jaccard(mrow.todense(), a.todense())  # with conversion
1000 loops, best of 3: 539 µs per loop

In [44]: timeit d.jaccard(mrowd, ad)  #  dense
10000 loops, best of 3: 173 µs per loop
```

======================

I need to rerun those tests because `d.jaccard` does not work with sparse (and `jaccard_fast` does not work with dense).  So separating the sparse row iteration issues from the `jaccard` calculation will take more work.

I've reworked `jaccard_fast` a bit:

```
def my_jaccard(mat, a):
    common = mat*a.T # sparse does the large matrix product well 
    dis=np.array([(row!=a).getnnz() for row in mat]) # iterative
    cA = common.A.ravel()
    return 1 - cA/(cA + dis)
```

It returns values that match `d.jaccard` run on the dense rows.  `d.jaccard` returns `1` for the rows where `common` is 0.  I don't seem to need a `cA` test (unless it is possible that both `cA` and `dis` are 0 at the same slot).

```
In [141]: r=np.array([d.jaccard(row,ad) for row in mat.todense()])

In [142]: r1=my_jaccard(mat,a)

In [143]: np.allclose(r,r1)
Out[143]: True
```

and speed is only half.  If I can rework the `dis` calc is should have similar speed.

```
In [144]: timeit r=np.array([d.jaccard(row,ad) for row in mat.todense()])
1 loops, best of 3: 783 ms per loop

In [145]: timeit r1=my_jaccard(mat,a)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.29 s per loop
```

A further tweak to the calc.  I mask out the `common` values that are 0.  This has 2 purposes - it ensures we don't have a divide by 0 problem, and it reduces the number of `dis` iterations, giving a small speed improvement.

```
def my_jaccard(mat, a):
    common=mat*a.T
    cA = common.A.ravel()
    mask = cA!=0
    cA = cA[mask]
    dis = np.array([(row!=a).getnnz() for row, b in zip(mat,mask) if b])
    ret = np.ones(mat.shape[0])
    ret[mask] = 1 - cA/(cA+dis)
    return ret
```

with this the time drops a bit.

```
In [188]: timeit my_jaccard(mat,a)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.04 s per loop
```

==================

There's an overlap in issues with [Python - Efficient Function with scipy sparse Matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37056258/python-efficient-function-with-scipy-sparse-matrices)

In that question I looked at comparing a sparse matrix with a 1 row matrix, and found that using `sparse.kron` to replicate the row, was the fastest way to replicated `numpy` broadcasting.

Using that idea in `jaccard` to calculate the `dis` array

```
def my_jaccard1(mat, a):
    common = mat*a.T
    cA = common.A.ravel()
    aM = sparse.kron(a,np.ones((mat.shape[0],1),int))
    dis = (mat!=aM).sum(1)
    ret = 1-cA/(cA+dis.A1)
    return ret
```

With this timings improve significantly (10x):

```
In [318]: timeit my_jaccard1(mat,a)
1 loops, best of 3: 97.1 ms per loop
```

I can apply masking as before to protect against divide by zero; but it actually slows down the calculation (to 140ms).

```
def my_jaccard3(mat, a):
    common = mat*a.T
    cA = common.A.ravel()
    mask = cA!=0
    cA = cA[mask]
    aM = sparse.kron(a,np.ones((len(cA),1),int))
    dis = (mat[mask,:]!=aM).sum(1)
    ret = np.ones(mat.shape[0])
    ret[mask] = 1 - cA/(cA+dis.A1) 
    return ret
```

========================

edit - test of the suspected case

```
In [75]: x,y= np.array([1,1,0,0,1,0]), np.array([0,0,1,0,1,0])

In [76]: d.jaccard(x,y)
Out[76]: 0.75

In [78]: jaccard_fast(sparse.csr_matrix(x),sparse.csr_matrix(y))
Out[78]: 0.75
```

My versions:

```
In [79]: my_jaccard(sparse.csr_matrix(x),sparse.csr_matrix(y))
Out[79]: array([ 0.75])
...
In [82]: my_jaccard3(sparse.csr_matrix(x),sparse.csr_matrix(y))
Out[82]: array([ 0.75])
```

(edit - explicitly use `sparse.kron`)

Comment: Apologies for not being able to check this earlier, but I think your solution does not produce same result as `d.jaccard`. E.g, try with vectors [1,1,0,0,1,0],[0,0,1,0,1,0]

Comment: Does `jacard_fast` get that case right?  I tried to replicate that (except for the 1 0 switch).

Comment: `jacard_fast` does get this case right, I checked. Apologies, I have to look into this when I have access to computation devices again tomorrow.

Comment: My version(s) match; may be I'm misunderstanding your example.

Comment: I get an`AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'sum'` at `dis = (mat[mask,:]!=aM).sum(1)` trying to  run your tests. my scipy version is 0.17.0 and numpy underneath is 0.11.0

Comment: The above error is caused as we try to compare a νmpy.n↓ayνmpy.n↓aynumpy.ndarray  (aM) with scipy.sparse.csrmatrixscipy.sparse.csrmatrixscipy.sparse.csr_matrix (mat). iImight be wrong here, but that is my understanding.

Comment: The two sides of the `!=` have have the same shape; otherwise it returns a scalar `False`.  The purpose of the `kron` is to create a `aM` with the right shape.

Comment: Are you using `np.kron` or `sparse.kron`?  I used the `sparse` one.

Comment: Thanks a for the clarification! was using `scipy.kron` instead `scipy.sparse.kron`. Apologies for my novice comments.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
def getrow_using_underlying_repr(a):
    for i,j in enumerate(a.indptr[:-1]):
        a.data[a.indptr[i]:a.indptr[i+1]]
```

It's more than 100 times faster than getrow():

```
Jaccard Fast:
CPU times: user 1.41 s, sys: 0 ns, total: 1.41 s
Wall time: 1.41 s
Jaccard Scipy (expanding to dense):
CPU times: user 19.9 ms, sys: 29.8 ms, total: 49.6 ms
Wall time: 49.3 ms
Jaccard Scipy (using getrow):
CPU times: user 1.48 s, sys: 1.27 ms, total: 1.48 s
Wall time: 1.48 s
getrow_using_underlying_repr:
CPU times: user 11 µs, sys: 1e+03 ns, total: 12 µs
Wall time: 13.8 µs
```

To understand the code see the explanation in the last version of the instantiation in the documentation:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix
To understand sparse CSR's underlying representation better see:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sparse-matrix-representations-set-3-csr/amp/?ref=rp
By investigating the the implementation of built-in getrow() in the source, it turns out that the reason of the slowness is that it doesn't use the underlying representation, but the matrix product of CSR sparse matrices.